# Understanding definitions of Cylinder Topology and Borel Cylinder $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand the definition of Cylinder Topology, and Borel Cylinder $\sigma$-algebra, in the picture below, and what it's described in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set#General_definition).

[image: picture from Cohen and Elliot's Stochastic Calculus]

Let $(\mathbb{R}^d)^{\mathbb{T}}=\{\text{functions } f:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d\}$

By Cylinder Topology I'm understanding the topology obtained from the following basis: $$\text{Basis}=\{A: A=\cap^n_{i=1}\{x_{t_i}\in B_i\} \text{ and } B_i \text{ is an open set of } \mathbb{R}^d \}$$

$\text{Cylinder Topology}=\{\cup_{i \in I} A_i: A_i \in \text{Basis}\}$

where $\cap^n_{i=1}\{x_{t_i}\in B_i\} = \{x \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^{\mathbb{T}}: x_{t_1}\in B_1, \cdots, x_{t_n}\in B_n\}$

and $$ \mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^d)^{\mathbb{T}})=\sigma(\text{Cylinder Topology}).$$

Am I understanding these definitions correctly?

Comment: The collection of all cylinder sets with open projections is not a topology - it is only a base for a topology.

Comment: @Matsmir I've just noticed your comment. I've just edited my post to reflect that =D. Thanks  ;)

Comment: Also I think that in Wiki page it is given that $\mathcal B((\mathbb R^d)^{\mathbb T}) = \sigma(Basis)$.

Comment: @Matsmir I think you're right... But then, I've also found out this other link on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806994/difference-between-borel-sigma-algebra-and-cylindrical-sigma-algebra 

The wikipedia page is referring to the cylindrical sigma algebra, and I think the picture is referring to the Borel sigma algebra generated from the cylindrical topology...

Comment: I see... It is not really clear which definition is meant in the picture since it mixes up cylinder sets and open sets in cylinder topology.